# Upgrade script for MediaWiki website with one external addon (wave 2)

Tags: bash

I have created the following Bash script to somewhat automate the upgrade of any [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Download) website which contains one extension ([ContactPage](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ContactPage)).

I have tested the essential parts of the script several times and also tested the version here line by line from the edit mode and I didn't find any problem with it; my website was updated as long as new versions for MediaWiki core and for ContactPage were available or if not, it stayed with the same versions.

### preface.sh:

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> ```
>
> **Set debug mode:**
>
> ```
> set -x && complete -r
> ```
>
> **Declare MediaWiki download variables:**
>
> ```
> latest_mediawiki_core="https://releases.wikimedia.org/mediawiki/1.34/mediawiki-1.34.2.tar.gz"
> latest_mediawiki_contactpage_extension="https://extdist.wmflabs.org/dist/extensions/ContactPage-REL1_34-48b0c07.tar.gz"
> ```
>
> **Declare web application backup variables:**
>
> ```
> current_date="$(date +%d-%m-%Y-%H-%M-%S)"
> general_backups_dir="${HOME}/mediawiki_general_backups"
> specific_backups_dir="${HOME}/mediawiki_specific_backups"
> ```
>
> **Declare web application root variables:**
>
> ```
> web_application_root="${HOME}/public_html"
> read domain
> domain_dir="${web_application_root}/${domain}"
> ```
>
> **Declare web application dbname:**
>
> ```
> read -s dbname
> ```
>
> **Declare web application dbusername:**
>
> ```
> read -s dbusername
> ```

### backups.sh:

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> ```
>
> **Create backup directories:**
>
> ```
> rm -rf "${general_backups_dir}"
> rm -rf "${specific_backups_dir}"
> mkdir -p "${general_backups_dir}"
> mkdir -p "${specific_backups_dir}"
> ```
>
> **Test backup directories:**
>
> ```
> ll "${general_backups_dir}"
> ll "${specific_backups_dir}"
> ```
>
> **Create specific backups:**
>
> ```
> cp "${domain_dir}/LocalSettings.php" "${specific_backups_dir}"
> cp "${domain_dir}/robots.txt" "${specific_backups_dir}"
> cp "${domain_dir}/${domain}.png" "${specific_backups_dir}"
> cp "${domain_dir}"/.htaccess* "${specific_backups_dir}" # This includes a shell glob;
> cp "${domain_dir}"/google*.html "${specific_backups_dir}" # This includes a shell glob;
> ```
>
> **Test specific backups:**
>
> ```
> ll "${specific_backups_dir}"
> ```
>
> **Create web application root backup:**
>
> ```
> zip -r "${general_backups_dir}/${domain}-directory-backup-${current_date}.zip" "${domain_dir}"
> ```
>
> **Test web application root backup:**
>
> ```
> ll "${general_backups_dir}"
> ```
>
> **Create web application database backup:**
>
> ```
> mysqldump -u"$dbusername" -p "$dbname" > "${general_backups_dir}/${dbusername}-${current_date}.sql"
> # -u && -p and dbname variable expansions shouldn't have "${}", rather, just "$";
> # If one wants to prompt dbusername password, -p should include a following whitespace character;
> # In general, dbusername and dbname variables must be different variables even if their values are the same;
> # Database Management Programs (i.e PHPMyAdmin) and mysqldump can produce databases in different sizes due to different data organization methods;
> ```
>
> **Test web application database backup:**
>
> ```
> ll "${general_backups_dir}"
> ```

### delete-download-install-and-configure-MediaWiki.sh:

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> ```
>
> **Prepare to download, install and configure CMS and specific backups:**
>
> ```
> cd "${web_application_root}"
> rm -rf "${domain_dir}"
> ```
>
> **Download and configure MediaWiki core:**
>
> ```
> wget "${latest_mediawiki_core}" &&
> find . -maxdepth 1 -iname 'mediawiki*.tar.gz' -type f -exec tar -xzf {} \; && 
> find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -iname '*mediawiki*' -execdir mv {} "${domain}" \; &&
> find . -maxdepth 1 -iname 'mediawiki*.tar.gz' -type f -exec rm {} \;
> ```
>
> **Download and configure MediaWiki ContactPage extension:**
>
> ```
> wget "${latest_mediawiki_contactpage_extension}" &&
> find . -maxdepth 1 -iname 'ContactPage*.tar.gz' -type f -exec tar -xzf {} \; &&
> find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -iname 'ContactPage*' -execdir mv {} "${domain}/extensions" \; &&
> find . -maxdepth 1 -iname 'ContactPage*.tar.gz' -type f -exec rm {} \;
> ```
>
> **Test previous operations:**
>
> ```
> ll
> ll "${domain_dir}/extensions"
> ```
>
> **Retreive specific backups to the new installation:**
>
> ```
> cp -a "${specific_backups_dir}"/.htaccess "${domain_dir}" # Only .htaccess file;
> cp -a "${specific_backups_dir}"/* "${domain_dir}" # All files besides .htaccess;
> ```
>
> **Test specific backups retreiving:**
>
> ```
> ll ${domain_dir}
> ```

### final-configurations.sh:

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> ```
>
> **Prepare to create and configure a new sitemap and to update database:**
>
> ```
> cd "${domain_dir}"
> ```
>
> **Create a new sitemap:**
>
> ```
> rm -rf "${domain_dir}/sitemap"
> mkdir -p "${domain_dir}/sitemap"
>
> php "${domain_dir}/maintenance/generateSitemap.php" \
> --memory-limit=50M \
> --fspath=/"${domain_dir}/sitemap" \
> --identifier="${domain}" \
> --urlpath=/sitemap/ \
> --server=https://"${domain}" \
> --compress=yes
> ```
>
> **Update database (One might need to change LocalSettings.php before doing so):**
>
> ```
> php "${domain_dir}/maintenance/update.php" --quick &&
> php maintenance/rebuildrecentchanges.php
> ```

Comment: Instead of segmenting the file for the purpose of post here, just dump the contents as is, and use comments inside bash for marking different sections.

Comment: The segments reflect how I document it the script in a `.sh` file, although here I only presented the `** COMMENT **` instead `## COMMENT ##` or similar ; let along, I have four different files stored on my cloud and PC...

Comment: Bash comments would make each line very long **here** ; I can put the comments under each line but I think it's even less comfortable than the current mode, but perhaps it's just me.